# Setting certificate trust in Swift 5.x for macOS

Tags: macos, swift5

I have been trying to understand how to handle trust for certificates in macOS using Swift 5.  I can add CA certificates using the command line but want to use code for an app I'm developing instead of relying on an external script and Process().

Here is the code that I have but I do not understand what value I'm supposed to pass in the function SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings .

```
func addCert(cert: String) {
    let certURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: cert, withExtension: "cer")!
    let certData = try! Data(contentsOf: certURL)
    let certificate: SecCertificate? = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certData as CFData)
    let addquery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassCertificate,
                                   kSecValueRef as String: certificate!,
                                   kSecAttrLabel as String: cert]
    let status = SecItemAdd(addquery as CFDictionary, nil)
    guard status == errSecSuccess else {
        print("error \(status) : " + (SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil)! as String))
        return
    }
    SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings(certificate!, .user, <trustSettingsDictOrArray: CFTypeRef>)
}
```

I read through the documentation and can see what "possible" values to use like trustAsRoot but do not know how to go about adding that to make the function work.  There isn't a lot of material on using this with Swift for macOS and any help would be greatly appreciated.

My ultimate goal is to add CA certificates to the user login.keychain-db to allow access to Sharepoint portals where I work.  I want these to be added and automatically trusted when the user clicks a button to call this function.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

So I was able to figure out what I needed to do by using an extension called Swiftify and converting old objective-c code to swift.  It made the swift implementation much more understandable to my problem.  Its a free extension on the App Store and I whole heartedly appreciate it.  Here is the final code that allowed me to programmatically install and trust a certificate.

```
func addCert(cert: String) {
    let certURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: cert, withExtension: "cer")!
    let certData = try! Data(contentsOf: certURL)
    let certificate: SecCertificate? = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certData as CFData)
    let addquery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassCertificate,
                                   kSecValueRef as String: certificate!,
                                   kSecAttrLabel as String: cert]
    let status = SecItemAdd(addquery as CFDictionary, nil)
    guard status == errSecSuccess else {
        print("error \(status) : " + (SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil)! as String))
        return
    }

    let result = SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings(certificate!, .user, [kSecTrustSettingsResult: NSNumber(value: SecTrustSettingsResult.trustAsRoot.rawValue)] as CFTypeRef)
    print("result = \(result) : " + (SecCopyErrorMessageString(result, nil)! as String))
}
```

I hope this helps a poor soul in the future with these types of problems.  I would suggest looking into creating a helper tool to handle privilege elevation if you are planning on importing a lot of certificates, otherwise you the user will have to type their password in for every certificate.